# Как поместить построенную HTML страницу на фрейм?

Tags: html, java

Есть страница, которую надо пропарсить, удалить ненужные элементы, затем собрать воедино и поместить на фрейм рядом с кнопками. С помощью каких библиотек возможно это реализовать?

Comment: почему в тегах `java`? Может для начала следует разобратся в разнице между `java` и `javascript`?

----

*"поместить на фрейм"*? Подробнее.

Comment: Потому что javascript тут не причем. Имею в виду то, что есть класс, наследуемый от JFrame, на нем помещены различные элементы... Так вот возможно ли поместить на эту форму страницу в виде элемента?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
            // Easiest connection (without authorization) 
            URL url = new URL("http://www.board74.ru/index.html");

            try {
                LineNumberReader r = new LineNumberReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                String s = r.readLine();
                while (s != null) {
                    System.out.println(s);
                    s = r.readLine();
                }
                r.close();
            } catch (IOException iOException) {
                iOException.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

можно так, можно еще как-то =) можно написать свой браузер со своей разметкой или есть библиотеки типа jsoup